# Report Provider to Clients

Tags: qlikview

I have a web solution with about 1000 clients. Nowadays they have access to reports that I provide as a PDF: an ASP.NET script executes SP's in the database and with PDFReactor I create a PDF. This is online and as you may already be guessing, it is unmanageable for large data sets.

I was thinking of using a reporting solution, as Power BI, Tableau or... Qlik. In my investigations I have found out that Qlik is the most complete solution for what I want. Nevertheless, I still have some questions, regarding the application architecture and how I can integrate Qlik with my application.

1. The first question is how I manage my users? I have a custom authentication provider and user management inside my application... What is the best way to integrate with Qlik? I manually configure all the clients in the Qlik Server also? There are endpoints to do it automatically?
2. The second question is how I manage what a client can see inside a Qlik document (QVW). I want to have several unique QVD, where several QVW get their data from. But I don't want to create a QVW for each client!! Can I filter a QVW based on a user authentication?
3. I would like that my clients could see the reports dynamically inside my web app. But my conclusion so far is that the web view of Qlik is static and that for more dynamism my users would have to use Qlik View desktop. Correct?
4. And this leads me to the final question: does my clients would have to pay licenses or is everything on my side and responsibility?

Thanks for  your help!

Regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

1. Out of the box QlikView Server (see 4.2) uses NTFS authentication (local windows users or `Active Directory`). There is something called DMS - ticket based authentication which allow non Windows users to be authorized to access apps. A bit more info [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Server/Content/QlikView-Server/QVSRM_Security_Overview.htm)
2. QlikView have something called `Section Access` which is on file (qvw) level. `Section Access` is part of the QV script. Basically you can create link between user name and data field. The main file will contain all the data but when the user open the document he/she can see only the data that its relevant to this username. More info [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/1.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/Security/DynamicDataReduction.htm) and [here](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-9039)

For example:

`user1 -> can see only UK data
 user2 -> can see UK and USA data
 user3 -> can see all the data
 ... etc`

3. The web app and the desktop app are the same. The web client provide same level of interaction as the desktop so you can slice and dice your data as you want

4.1 QV desktop (personal edition) is free but you can open up to 5 qvw files which are not "yours" (not created with the current instance of the personal edition) and the clients need to install it locally on their computers

4.2 QV server is not free. With QV server all the clients are accessing the QV apps via the browser. You (as administrator) are buying the licenses from Qlik Partner and it's up to you if you want to charge your customers or not (and how much)